# What's wrong with this BIND zone definition?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, bind, nameserver

```
@       IN SOA  @ ns.mycompany.com. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
@        IN      NS           ns.mycompany.com.
@        IN      CNAME   web
web    IN      A             10.0.0.1
```

Comment: Being you didn't tell us what the problem is or what you are trying to do, I'll give you a link to information that should help you decide for yourself. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file

Answer (score 2):

```
@       IN SOA  @ ns.mycompany.com. ...
@        IN      NS           ns.mycompany.com.
@        IN      CNAME   web   # <-- this isn't legal
```

It is illegal to have a CNAME at the for the same record as any other record types.  This means you are violating the RFCs by trying to have an CNAME at the zone apex, since the SOA, and NS records are required at the zone apex.